# Execute PHP using JavaScript onclick submit

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, onclick

How do I execute PHP using a JavaScript onclick button?
I can get the form to submit, but the PHP does not get executed. I assume it's because `if(isset($_POST['form']))`

Here is the PHP I want to execute:

```
if(isset($_POST['form']))
{
    if(!isset($error))
    {
        $database->query('UPDATE table SET field = :value WHERE id = :id', array(':field' => $value, ':id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Here is my button that is BEFORE my `<form>` tag:

```
<div onclick="javascript: $(\'#form\').submit();">Update</div>
```

And of course my `<form>` tag looks something like this:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <select name="value">
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">Value3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I can get the form to submit, but the PHP does not get executed. I assume it's because `if(isset($_POST['form']))`

Comment: I can't use the `name=form` in the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP generally runs server side. JavaScript generally runs in the browser. You need to put the PHP in the file `blah.php` on the server.

Comment: I can get the form to submit, but the PHP does not get executed. I assume it's because `if(isset($_POST['form']))`

Comment: Change `$_POST['form']` to `$_POST['foo']` where `foo` is the name attribute of the `input` element you care about.

Comment: Ah, of course. How stupid of me. Since I might have more than one `input` field in the form I was hoping to use the `name=form` in the `<form>` tag. But your suggestion will work.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you have a `$_POST['form']` variable.  `$_POST` will contain all of your form element's id's like email, phone, name, etc...  `$_POST['email']`, but would likely not contain a general 'form' key.

I would use
    `if (isset($_POST))`

Comment: I thought about using that but I have two forms on the page.